# Convert String to JSON in Java REST

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a JSON object, generated from a REST service, that looks like this:

```
  {
    "name": "mark",
    "other_details": "{age:34, gender:male}"
  }
```

In the "other_details" param, the value has to be converted to a JSON object, which ultimately should look like:

```
{
    "name": "mark",
    "other_details": "{
                          "age":"34", 
                          "gender":"male"
                      }"
}
```

My POJO looks like:

```
class Profile{
          String name;
          String other_details;
         //getters and setters
}
```

I need some help regarding converting the value of the "other_details" param(which is a string) into a JSON.
I did try to use Jackson, but it was of no use.

any ideas, how should I proceed !!

Comment: In your Java code "other_details" is represented as a String, but in your JSON it is mapped as an object.

Answer (score 2):

You pojo should look like

```
public class Profile{
   String name;
   OtherDetailsClass other_details;
   //getters and setters
}
```

Other Details Class should look like

```
public class OtherDetailsClass {
    String age;
    String gender;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I did try this, but I guess, its because of the way the other_details value is stored.
The other_details value is fetched from the database, where that column is of String type and is of format  {age:34, gender:male} .

Is it possible to parse and convert it to JSON format in POJO.

Comment: use @JsonProperty(value = "other_details") for mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a POJO for other_details.

```
class Profile{
          String name;
          OtherDetails other_details;
         //getters and setters
}

class OtherDetails{
          String name;
          String gender;
         //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I did try this, but I guess, its because of the way the other_details value is stored.
The other_details value is fetched from the database, where that column is of String type and is of format  {age:34, gender:male} .

Is it possible to parse and convert it to JSON format in POJO ?